# Jenkins - BuildWith parameters

Tags: jenkins

Currently I have a python script which reads and returns the build version from the Build Server.
But I couldn't find an easy mechanism of passing the version value as an input value when jobs are run with "Build With Parameter" option. 
The Current job is supposed to run on a scheduled manner. So it should automatically run the script, pick the version, auto populate and trigger.

I have done this by using the Jenkins REST API with buildwithparameters option, but I would like to know if this can be done without the REST.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your python script to create text file containing version number(instead of returning). Then in build script, read this file to get version info.